# UIView container disappears when I move it's Y origin down

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have UIView which is container for button "send" and textView.
When I starting editing I have keyboard on the screen and I change Y origin of the container to move it higher and not be covered by keyboard.

When I finish editing I got keyboard hidden and my container(UIView with button and textView) just disappears! But if I turn simulator right or left this became visible again.

Here is the animation code that move my container up and down:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    self.messagePromptLabel.hidden = messageTextView.hasText() ? true : false

}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if !self.messageTextView.hasText()  {
        self.messagePromptLabel.hidden = false
    }
}

func didTapScrollView(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {

    let dict: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize: NSValue = dict.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let frameKeyboardSize: CGRect = keyboardSize.CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.chatScrollView.frame.origin.y -= frameKeyboardSize.height
        self.messageView.frame.origin.y -= frameKeyboardSize.height

        }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.chatScrollView.frame.origin.y = self.chatScrollViewOriginY!
        self.messageView.frame.origin.y = self.messageTextViewOriginY!

        }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
    }
}
```

**Some additional code** 
This code may help find out something.

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var chatScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var messagePromptLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messageView: UIView!

var chatScrollViewOriginY: CGFloat?
var messageTextViewOriginY: CGFloat?

var messageArray = [String]()
var senderArray = [String]()

var currentUserImage: UIImage?
var recipientImage: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    messageTextView.addSubview(messagePromptLabel)
    self.title = recipientNickname

    chatScrollViewOriginY = self.chatScrollView.frame.origin.y
    messageTextViewOriginY = self.messageTextView.frame.origin.y
    print(" messageTextViewOriginY \(messageTextViewOriginY)")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTapScrollView")
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    chatScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    chatScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    self.messagePromptLabel.hidden = messageTextView.hasText() ? true : false

}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if !self.messageTextView.hasText()  {
        self.messagePromptLabel.hidden = false
    }
}

func didTapScrollView(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**Question:**
What make my UIView container invisible all the time when I hidding keyboard and make it visible when I turn my phone left or right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this code in your send button action:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```